# ERROR in WSO2 BAM 2.0.1: try to close a closed DB

Tags: wso2, wso2-bam, wso2-esb

After running WSO2 BAM 2.0.1 for a while with data from AS and ESB I can see this error time to time. I use the default configuration I just put the toolboxes for AS and ESB in BAM. even with this error BAM work ok and I can see the statistic with no problem:

```
TID: [0] [BAM] [2012-11-04 22:22:08,613] ERROR {org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask} -  IO error in map input file file:/var/BAM/wso2bam-2.0.1/repository/data/hive/warehouse-1234/appserverstatsperdaydatafetcher {org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask}
TID: [0] [BAM] [2012-11-04 22:22:08,613] ERROR {org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask} -  IO error in map input file file:/var/BAM/wso2bam-2.0.1/repository/data/hive/warehouse-1234/appserverstatsperdaydatafetcher {org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask}
TID: [0] [BAM] [2012-11-04 22:22:08,650] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.hadoop.hive.jdbc.storage.db.DBRecordReader} -  Failed to close {org.wso2.carbon.hadoop.hive.jdbc.storage.db.DBRecordReader}
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Database is already closed (to disable automatic closing at VM shutdown, add ";DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE" to the db URL) [90121-140]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:327)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:167)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:144)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:133)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.checkClosed(JdbcConnection.java:1348)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.checkClosedForWrite(JdbcConnection.java:1333)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.commit(JdbcConnection.java:413)
        at org.wso2.carbon.hadoop.hive.jdbc.storage.db.DBRecordReader.close(DBRecordReader.java:175)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveRecordReader.doClose(HiveRecordReader.java:50)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveContextAwareRecordReader.close(HiveContextAwareRecordReader.java:96)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.close(MapTask.java:254)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:439)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:371)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:210)
TID: [0] [BAM] [2012-11-04 22:22:08,880] ERROR {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecDriver} -  Ended Job = job_local_0001 with errors {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecDriver}
TID: [0] [BAM] [2012-11-04 22:22:08,880] ERROR {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecDriver} -  Ended Job = job_local_0001 with errors {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecDriver}
TID: [0] [BAM] [2012-11-04 22:22:08,884] ERROR {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecDriver} -  Error during job, obtaining debugging information... {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecDriver}
TID: [0] [BAM] [2012-11-04 22:22:08,884] ERROR {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecDriver} -  Error during job, obtaining debugging information... {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecDriver}
adoop.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.executeQuery(HiveStatement.java:189)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl$ScriptCallable.call(HiveExecutorServiceImpl.java:325)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl$ScriptCallable.call(HiveExecutorServiceImpl.java:225)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
TID: [0] [BAM] [2012-11-04 22:22:09,557] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.task.HiveScriptExecutorTask} -  Error while executing script : service_stats_848 {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.task.HiveScriptExecutorTask}
org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.exception.HiveExecutionException: Error while executing Hive script.Query returned non-zero code: 9, cause: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl.execute(HiveExecutorServiceImpl.java:110)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.task.HiveScriptExecutorTask.execute(HiveScriptExecutorTask.java:60)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ntask.core.impl.TaskQuartzJobAdapter.execute(TaskQuartzJobAdapter.java:56)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
TID: [0] [BAM] [2012-11-04 22:24:00,003]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.task.HiveScriptExecutorTask} -  Running script executor task for script esb_stats_0. [Sun Nov 04 22:24:00 CST 2012] {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.task.HiveScriptExecutorTask}

TID: [0] [BAM] [2012-11-04 22:24:00,009]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.task.HiveScriptExecutorTask} -  Running script executor task for script service_stats_848. [Sun Nov 04 22:24:00 CST 2012] {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.task.HiveScriptExecutorTask}
TID: [0] [BAM] [2012-11-04 22:24:07,697]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.cassandra.server.CarbonCassandraAuthenticator} -  The key is not present in the cache... {org.wso2.carbon.cassandra.server.CarbonCassandraAuthenticator}
TID: [0] [BAM] [2012-11-04 22:25:15,219] ERROR {org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask} -  IO error in map input file file:/var/BAM/wso2bam-2.0.1/repository/data/hive/warehouse-1234/esbmediationstatsperdaydatafetcher {org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask}
TID: [0] [BAM] [2012-11-04 22:25:15,219] ERROR {org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask} -  IO error in map input file file:/var/BAM/wso2bam-2.0.1/repository/data/hive/warehouse-1234/esbmediationstatsperdaydatafetcher {org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask}
TID: [0] [BAM] [2012-11-04 22:25:15,224] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.hadoop.hive.jdbc.storage.db.DBRecordReader} -  Failed to close {org.wso2.carbon.hadoop.hive.jdbc.storage.db.DBRecordReader}
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Database is already closed (to disable automatic closing at VM shutdown, add ";DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE" to the db URL) [90121-140]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:327)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:167)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:144)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:133)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.checkClosed(JdbcConnection.java:1348)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.checkClosedForWrite(JdbcConnection.java:1333)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.commit(JdbcConnection.java:413)
        at org.wso2.carbon.hadoop.hive.jdbc.storage.db.DBRecordReader.close(DBRecordReader.java:175)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveRecordReader.doClose(HiveRecordReader.java:50)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveContextAwareRecordReader.close(HiveContextAwareRecordReader.java:96)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.close(MapTask.java:254)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:439)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:371)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:210)
TID: [0] [BAM] [2012-11-04 22:25:15,606] ERROR {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecDriver} -  Ended Job = job_local_0001 with errors {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecDriver}
TID: [0] [BAM] [2012-11-04 22:25:15,606] ERROR {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecDriver} -  Ended Job = job_local_0001 with errors {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecDriver}
TID: [0] [BAM] [2012-11-04 22:25:15,610] ERROR {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecDriver} -  Error during job, obtaining debugging information... {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecDriver}
TID: [0] [BAM] [2012-11-04 22:25:15,610] ERROR {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecDriver} -  Error during job, obtaining debugging information... {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecDriver}
hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.executeQuery(HiveStatement.java:189)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl$ScriptCallable.call(HiveExecutorServiceImpl.java:325)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl$ScriptCallable.call(HiveExecutorServiceImpl.java:225)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
TID: [0] [BAM] [2012-11-04 22:25:16,271] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.task.HiveScriptExecutorTask} -  Error while executing script : esb_stats_0 {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.task.HiveScriptExecutorTask}
org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.exception.HiveExecutionException: Error while executing Hive script.Query returned non-zero code: 9, cause: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl.execute(HiveExecutorServiceImpl.java:110)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.task.HiveScriptExecutorTask.execute(HiveScriptExecutorTask.java:60)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ntask.core.impl.TaskQuartzJobAdapter.execute(TaskQuartzJobAdapter.java:56)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
TID: [0] [BAM] [2012-11-04 22:27:00,007]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.task.HiveScriptExecutorTask} -  Running script executor task for script esb_stats_0. [Sun Nov 04 22:27:00 CST 2012] {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.task.HiveScriptExecutorTask}

TID: [0] [BAM] [2012-11-04 22:27:00,009]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.task.HiveScriptExecutorTask} -  Running script executor task for script service_stats_848. [Sun Nov 04 22:27:00 CST 2012] {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.task.HiveScriptExecutorTask}
TID: [0] [BAM] [2012-11-04 22:27:07,936]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.cassandra.server.CarbonCassandraAuthenticator} -  The key is not present in the cache... {org.wso2.carbon.cassandra.server.CarbonCassandraAuthenticator}
```

Also I see this error:

```
TID: [0] [BAM] [2012-11-04 23:42:00,013]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.task.HiveScriptExecutorTask} -  Running script executor task for script esb_stats_0. [Sun Nov 04 23:42:00 CST 2012] {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.task.HiveScriptExecutorTask}
TID: [0] [BAM] [2012-11-04 23:42:00,022]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.task.HiveScriptExecutorTask} -  Running script executor task for script service_stats_848. [Sun Nov 04 23:42:00 CST 2012] {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.task.HiveScriptExecutorTask}
TID: [0] [BAM] [2012-11-04 23:42:08,261]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.cassandra.server.CarbonCassandraAuthenticator} -  The key is not present in the cache... {org.wso2.carbon.cassandra.server.CarbonCassandraAuthenticator}
TID: [0] [BAM] [2012-11-04 23:42:55,866] ERROR {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task} -  Execution failed with exit status: 2 {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task}
TID: [0] [BAM] [2012-11-04 23:42:55,866] ERROR {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task} -  Execution failed with exit status: 2 {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task}
TID: [0] [BAM] [2012-11-04 23:42:55,867] ERROR {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task} -  Obtaining error information {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task}
TID: [0] [BAM] [2012-11-04 23:42:55,867] ERROR {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task} -  Obtaining error information {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task}
TID: [0] [BAM] [2012-11-04 23:42:55,867] ERROR {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task} -
Task failed!
Task ID:
  Stage-0

Logs:
 {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task}
TID: [0] [BAM] [2012-11-04 23:42:55,867] ERROR {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task} -
Task failed!
Task ID:
  Stage-0

Logs:
 {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task}
TID: [0] [BAM] [2012-11-04 23:42:55,868] ERROR {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task} -  /var/BAM/wso2bam-2.0.1/repository/logs//wso2carbon.log {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task}
TID: [0] [BAM] [2012-11-04 23:42:55,868] ERROR {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task} -  /var/BAM/wso2bam-2.0.1/repository/logs//wso2carbon.log {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task}
TID: [0] [BAM] [2012-11-04 23:42:55,868] ERROR {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecDriver} -  Execution failed with exit status: 2 {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecDriver}
TID: [0] [BAM] [2012-11-04 23:42:55,868] ERROR {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecDriver} -  Execution failed with exit status: 2 {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecDriver}
TID: [0] [BAM] [2012-11-04 23:42:55,868] ERROR {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver} -  FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver}
TID: [0] [BAM] [2012-11-04 23:42:55,868] ERROR {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver} -  FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver}
TID: [0] [BAM] [2012-11-04 23:42:55,869] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl} -  Error while executing Hive script.
Query returned non-zero code: 9, cause: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl}
java.sql.SQLException: Query returned non-zero code: 9, cause: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.executeQuery(HiveStatement.java:189)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl$ScriptCallable.call(HiveExecutorServiceImpl.java:325)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl$ScriptCallable.call(HiveExecutorServiceImpl.java:225)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
TID: [0] [BAM] [2012-11-04 23:42:55,872] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.task.HiveScriptExecutorTask} -  Error while executing script : service_stats_848 {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.task.HiveScriptExecutorTask}
org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.exception.HiveExecutionException: Error while executing Hive script.Query returned non-zero code: 9, cause: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl.execute(HiveExecutorServiceImpl.java:110)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.task.HiveScriptExecutorTask.execute(HiveScriptExecutorTask.java:60)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ntask.core.impl.TaskQuartzJobAdapter.execute(TaskQuartzJobAdapter.java:56)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the hive script, where the jdbc url is defined, could you try adding the ";DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE" and see whether the exception goes away.

Comment: Yes I see this string in the log. i put this question just to show the error.

Comment: Ah OK! IIUC, when you put that string the error goes away. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Well, I´m a step back :-D i start to see the error again. I put what the error and you suggested but with not success :   'mapred.jdbc.url' = 'jdbc:h2:repository/database/samples/BAM_STATS_DB;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE',  during a fresh start I start to see the error again org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Database is already closed (to disable automatic closing at VM shutdown, add ";DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE" to the db URL) [90121-140]